# We are to evaluate the problem at the given limit using pi and redicals in our answer as needed.

Tags: integration

The Problem:
$$
\int\!\sin^5(4x)\,dx
$$
The formula that I used from the integration tables is:

$$
\int\!\sin^n(u)\,du
$$
My final answer is
$$
(-1/5)\left(\sin^4(4x)\cos(4x)-(4/5)\cos(4x)+(4/15)\right)\cos^3(4x)+C
$$
This answer is wrong.  If anyone can tell me if I am using the wrong formula or shine some light on what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please check that the edit is what you intended: when you originally wrote the problem, an important right parenthesis was missing in the answer you got.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is probably a recurrence down to $\sin^{n-2}$.  But for odd $n$ we can do this, after substituting $u=4x, dx=\frac 14 du$: $$\begin {align}\int \sin^5 (4x)\; dx&=\frac 14 \int \sin^5 u\; du\\&=\frac 14\int(1-\cos^2u)^2\sin u \;du\\&=\frac 14\int(1-2\cos^2 u +\cos^4 u)\sin u \; du\\&=\frac 14(-\cos u+\frac 23\cos^3 u-\frac 15 \cos^5 u)
\\ &=\frac 14(-\cos (4x)+\frac 23\cos^3 (4x)-\frac 15 \cos^5 (4x)) \end {align}$$